# Globbing for only files in Bash

Tags: bash, glob

I'm having a bit of trouble with globs in Bash. For example:

```
echo *
```

This prints out all of the files and folders in the current directory.
e.g. (file1 file2 folder1 folder2)

```
echo */
```

This prints out all of the folders with a / after the name.
e.g. (folder1/ folder2/)

How can I glob for just the files?
e.g. (file1 file2)

I know it could be done by parsing ls but also know that [it is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I tried using extended blobbing but couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

WIthout using any external utility you can try `for loop` with `glob support`:

```
for i in *; do [ -f "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was thinking of. Thank you very much. I'm not sure I totally understand it. Is it iterating over the glob and [-f "$i"] is testing if it is a file? EDIT: Just checked the man page for test. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnP, yes. You could also use `[ ! -d "$i" ]` to test that the current item is *not a directory* -- You would then be including symbolic links and other types of files, just explicitly not directories.

Comment: Yes exactly! For loop iterates each entry in the current directory and `[ -f "$i" ]` checks whether that entry is a regular file.

Comment: (!) `test -f` just tests for a plain (regular) file, not checking for block special files (like `/dev/null`), sockets, symlinks [..].

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if you can solve this with globbing, but you can certainly solve it with [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: cleanest, especially as used in args for some other command, e.g. `perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)`. Oh, minor thing: maxdepth must come first to avoid the warning: "you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type (...)"

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you want in bash like this:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
echo !(*/)
```

But note that what this actually does is match "not directory-likes."
It will still match dangling symlinks, symlinks pointing to not-directories, device nodes, fifos, etc.

It won't match symlinks pointing to directories, though.

If you want to iterate over normal files and nothing more, use `find -maxdepth 1 -type f`.

The safe and robust way to use it goes like this:

```sh
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
  printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Your bash-only solution matches exactly the same as `echo *` for me

Comment: Also to activate the extglob option, you would have to use `shopt -s extglob`, as `shopt extglob` only shows if the option is set.

Comment: Upvoting for the safe way to use find, note that the `extglob` solution doesn't work, at leat not in bash 5.

Answer (score 2):

My go to in this scenario is to use the `find` command. I just had to use it, to find/replace dozens of instances in a given directory. I'm sure there are many other ways of skinning this cat, but the pure `for` example above, isn't recursive.

```
for file in $( find path/to/dir -type f -name '*.js' );
    do sed -ie 's#FIND#REPLACEMENT#g' "$file";
    done
```