# Why does $1*$2 display filenames of everything in its directory?

Tags: bash, glob

This is something I stumbled on when I made a mistake in my code (forgot `$(())` lol), so I've fixed my silly mistake already, but why does `$1*$2` give you a list of files and folders in the directory that the script is in?

Here is an example:

script.sh:

```
echo $1*$2
```

```
$ bash script.sh
random.bmp script.sh some text document.odt test file.txt test folder
```

The same thing happens if the command is just directly issued:

```
$ echo $1*$2
random.bmp script.sh some text document.odt test file.txt test folder
```

Does anyone know why it acts like this? Is there any documentation anywhere on the function? I briefly looked around about this but didn't find anyone else confused about it.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html

Comment: Please replace all links to images with its text. Take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: That's a glob (following parameter expansion), subject to pathname expansion, not an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Are you familiar with **globbing**? I think that's what you're looking for. Otherwise, what are the values of `$1` and `$2`? (They're probably both null.) What result were you expecting instead? BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thank you DiegoTorresMilano for the answer and Cyrus and wjandrea for helping me clean up my mess of a post =]

Comment: and for your curiosity @wjandrea, it was just a very basic script to add two numbers the user inputs as command-line arguments in the script to display the area of a square. so the code should have looked like this: `area=$(($1 * $2))`

Comment: $1 = "", $2 = "", You are left with `echo *`. Which is the CWD `ls` of files. try `echo *.txt` (glob/expansion of just .txt files). See here also - https://linuxhint.com/bash_echo/

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745656/globbing-for-only-files-in-bash & https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569888/503621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## Globs
>
> "Glob" is the common name for a set of Bash features that match or expand specific types of patterns. Some synonyms for globbing (depending on the context in which it appears) are [pattern matching](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), pattern expansion, filename expansion, and so on. A glob may look like `*.txt` and, when used to match filenames, is sometimes called a "wildcard".
>
> Traditional shell globs use a very simple syntax, which is less expressive than a [RegularExpression](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression). Most characters in a glob are treated literally, but a `*` matches 0 or more characters, a `?` matches precisely one character, and `[...]` matches any single character in a specified set (see [Ranges](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Ranges) below). All globs are implicitly anchored at both start and end.

-- [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

---

Official documentation: [Filename Expansion (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)